# Using SQL OUTPUT for INSERT into a table with Identity (or default values)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting records into a table (Payments) that require a sequence number. I get and increment this sequence number from another table (SequenceNumbers) using an UPDATE statement with a OUTPUT clause.

```
UPDATE [SequenceNumbers] SET SequenceNo = SequenceNo + 1 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.SequenceNo 
    WHERE EstateId = @EstateId
```

I was hoping to be able to combine the above UPDATE statement together with the Payments INSERT statement using OUTPUT INTO such as below

```
UPDATE [SequenceNumbers] SET Sequence = Sequence + 1 
    OUTPUT @EstateId AS EstateId, 
       INSERTED.SequenceNo AS SequenceNo
    INTO Payments
    WHERE EstateId = @EstateId
```

but when tested you have to supply all fields in the target table. What I want to do is use the automatic Identity value for the Id field in the Payments table together with default values for any missing fields.

I then need to return the Id (Identity) value in the Payments table to the caller.

I wondering if this is possible or whether there is another alternative?

I have put simplified examples of the Payments and SequenceNumbers tables below for reference.

```
CREATE TABLE [Payments](
    [EstateId]   INT NOT NULL,
    [Id]         INT NOT NULL IDENTITY , 
    [SequenceNo] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    .... other fields 
    PRIMARY KEY ([EstateId], [Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [SequenceNumbers] (
    [EstateId]   INT NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNo] INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EstateId] ASC)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to **specify** which columns in `Payments` to insert into:

```
UPDATE [SequenceNumbers] 
SET Sequence = Sequence + 1 
  OUTPUT Inserted.EstateId, Inserted.SequenceNo
  INTO Payments(EstateId, SequenceNo)     -- define what columns to insert into!
WHERE EstateId = @EstateId
```

Comment: Thanks marc don't know how I did not try that!. Do you know of any way to return the Identity field from the payments table or should I ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @JamesWhittred - `Scope_identity` might work [but there is some quirkiness in this area](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/765809/odd-behaviour-of-scope-identity-with-insert-into) so you'd need to test.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I have tried both `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY` as either an additional OUTPUT clause as well as a SELECT. It always returns NULL. This aligns with the third scenario in the link you shared. I am currently returning the SequenceNo as an additional OUTPUT clause then doing a new SELECT to find the inserted Payment table record. Would have been good to get it all in one statement but at least the sequence number increment and payment insert are happening in the one transaction.